# Openstack - No route to host on port 22

Tags: python, ssh, openstack, fabric, openstack-nova

I am trying to deploy an application on a private Openstack cloud. The application is based on the client-server model with the server running on a Virtual Machine on the cloud and having a floating IP address. When queried by the client (running on the cloud or outside) through REST API, the server spawns local VMs in the cloud (which don't have floating IPs) as and when required to serve the query. I am using [nova](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-novaclient) client API for spawning the VMs.

After spawning a local VM in the cloud from the server, I am trying to copy and run the code on the local VM using [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/). When I try to run a Fabric task to copy the code, I get this error -

```
DEBUG MSG:: command to run - python copyCode.py <local VM's IP>

Fatal error: Low level socket error connecting to host <local VM's IP> on port 22: No route to host (tried 1 time)

Underlying exception:
    No route to host

Aborting.
```

where `copyCode.py` (a script invoked from the server using `subprocess.Popen`) has a Fabric task which uses `put` API as shown [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.put).

I have disabled the host-key checking on the server as shown in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/19563/how-do-i-skip-the-known-host-question-the-first-time-i-connect-to-a-machine-vi), so I think the problem might not be arising because of the authentication requirements. I can also ssh/run `python copyCode.py <local VM's IP>` command from another shell while this process is running on the server to get the desired result (i.e. the code gets copied) without producing any such error.

Am I missing something here? Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Comment: It looks like `No route to host` is a ssh error, not a fabric/or copyCode.py error. Are you sure you can connect using just `ssh user@host`?

Comment: I can connect using `ssh user@host` from a different shell while this process is still running. I tested this by blocking this process where I get error, and then trying to `ssh user@host` at the same time. Did I miss to test anything else?

Comment: Im out of ideas. The only thing left is to see the code for the `fabfile.py` and `copyCode.py` and see what youre doing in there. Strip it out to the bare minimum where you can reproduce the bug.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try to dig deeper.
The strange thing is `python copyCode.py <local VM's IP>` is the same command I run from a different shell while this process is blocked, and it works.